# Using jQuery ajax in UIWebView.EvaluateJavascript()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

In my app I am using UIWebView in MonoTouch to evaluate some javascript. The javascript needs to retrieve some json using ajax from a service. When the ajax finishes it calls back into the app using NSUrlProtocol.

This works very well as long as I am using XMLHttpRequest for the ajax stuff. But when using jQuery.getJSON or jQuery.ajax it does not work at all. In fact the request does not even get executed by the UIWebView. (I can tell this since the NSUrlProtocol is notified for every Url being loaded). The service is an ASP.NET MVC4 Web API app which is setup to handle jsonp and cross service scripting. It works very well from every scenario I can come up with except this one.

Any suggestions on what may cause jQuery to fail?

Comment: how are you loading jQuery - via a remote request, or is it embedded in your app?  Can you verify it is loading correctly, and can you use it to execute a simple selector?

Comment: I have a local file containing jQuery which is included as content (tried google apis as well, no change).

Stuff like $("#myDiv").html() works great so at least those parts of jQuery are loaded correctly as far as I can tell.